# Twitter typeahead.js error in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, typeahead.js

I am getting an UNDEFINED error back from the following. I want exact matches to show up. Not needing typeahead for each character. The UNDEFINED error is showing up in the typeahead, so I know I am getting close.

```
// my route
   Route::get('getUsers/{q}', function($q)
 {
   return User::where('username', 'like', $q)->get();
});

//html
   <input type='text' class="invites" />

//jQuery
   $('.invites').typeahead([
  {
    name: 'username',
    remote: '/getUsers/%QUERY'
  }
 ]);
```

Thanks in advance much for taking a look!

Comment: Can you post here the result from hitting `/geUsers/<some-query>`? I suspect the format you're returning is wrong. The way you're using Typeahead, it should either be a JSON array of string, or a JSON array of objects, each containing `"value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the route, try post or any:

```
Route::post('getUsers/{q}', function($q)
```